# How/are you supposed to use the DKPro libraries with UIMA Ruta?

Tags: eclipse, maven, uima, ruta, dkpro-core

I have studied the default UIMA Ruta Workbench Eclipse project enough to significantly understand its moving parts - for instance, why the `input/` and `output/` folders behave as they do, how to accomplish the project using the `jcasgen` and other Maven plugins, etc.

But even after hours of studying the project and playing with Maven to try to get it to work, I still have a lot of trouble doing something very simple: using the `DKPro` libraries (the types especially) from a `Ruta` script.

My fundamental question is this: **what is the path of least resistence towards using the types and analysis components from the DKPro and TC libraries within a Ruta script?**

My specific questions are:

1. I noticed that in the `desc/type` folder of many `api` jars there are `TypeSystemDescription` XML files that would appear to be appropriate for use with Ruta. Is there some way of getting a "master" `TypeSystemDescription` XML file for the `DKPro` components?
2. Is there a project of significant complexity that uses both `Ruta` and `DKPro` that I can study?
3. What is the distinction between an `AnalysisEngine` as in what you do with `Ruta` scripts and an `Analysis Component` you write in Java?

**Edited** to reflect less frustration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the Ruta and DKPro people do workshops together and sit happily around the campfire afterwards - or at least in a cocktail bar and have some drinks. Unfortunately, we don't get around to doing that very often.

The kind and number of questions you are asking calls for a tutorial ;)

Did you have a look the slides and examples from our [joint workshop at GSCL 2013](https://docs.google.com/document/d/18BfopkrOuGlhqybPf4z25_FYbA5hal7YvS7hSod4_-U/pub)?

It includes several examples of how to use DKPro Core and Ruta together. In those examples, there is a Maven project responsible for fetching the DKPro Core dependencies and separate Ruta projects then have a dependency on that Maven project and use the analysis engines.

It should also work to have a single project with both, the Ruta and Maven natures.

1. The way to get a single type descriptor for all DKPro Core types in your classpath (or rather for all uimaFIT-enabled types in your classpath) is

   ```
   import org.apache.uima.fit.factory.TypeSystemDescriptionFactory;

   OutputStream os = ...
   TypeSystemDescriptionFactory.createTypeSystemDescription().toXML(os);
   ```
2. Check out the [GSCL 2013 tutorial examples](https://docs.google.com/document/d/18BfopkrOuGlhqybPf4z25_FYbA5hal7YvS7hSod4_-U/pub).
3. `AnalysisComponent` represents the view from the *inside*, i.e. from the perspective of the developer of components (the view from within the framework). `AnalysisEngine` represents the view from the outside, i.e. from the user of a component/workflow. However, typically one would say "I'm implementing a new analysis engine" and mean "I'm going to subclass `JCasAnnotator_ImplBase` (an implementation of `AnalysisComponent`)". See also [this post](http://markmail.org/message/w4fffq32rt57yh6p) on the UIMA developer mailing list.

*Disclosure:* I am a DKPro Core developer and an Apache UIMA developer.

Comment: Sorry for the tone of the original question... it reflected a lot of frustration. I ended up figuring out that I could actually import type descriptors from you via `IMPORT desc.type.` (dur on my part). The Ruta intellisense leaves some to be desired and I think the namespacing is way too ambiguous or aggressive or both. I got the impression you guys didn't respect Ruta from some post I read somewhere (maybe I can find it) where it was recommended not to use Ruta for several reasons :) - I will *definitely* be checking out the tutorial tonight

Comment: To be clear I am really enjoying using your libraries; it is a real privilege and I can tell how much blood sweat and tears have gone into them already (and I'm not even through investigating the core, let alone TC or other projects)... so as a follow-up, how active are you in development and is there a users' group or mailing list or other community resource you recommend? I don't intend to spam or even post a single question outside of SO but i wouldn't mind seeing what you all are up to

Comment: We're happy to get your questions and comments on the mailing lists of the respective projects. Apache UIMA has a users mailing list and since Ruta and uimaFIT are subproject of UIMA, they use the same one. All the different DKPro projects have their own users mailing lists on Google Groups - or just watch our Github projects.

Comment: Thanks for the info again. I've got one more question for you on this thread at least - is there an obvious choice for DKPro's most impressive, easy-to-provision, demoware? Some times folks set up web servers that are preloaded with the right dependencies and a web client, etc...

Comment: The standalone Groovy scripts are the best since bread came sliced ;) https://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-core/groovy/recipes/